# Transitionend event fired way too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

So I tried to animate a div moving on a page and changing it's `position` property after transition finished. But `transitionend` event was firing way too soon and I couldn't figure out why. See answer.

Answer (score -1):

#### TL;DR

> Visibility transitions faster than other properties. Place desired property in a condition inside callback.

After a while I figured out that for some reason visibility transitioned much faster than other properties. Don't know why. So after I placed the body of transitionend callback in a condition, it worked.

```
.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd' +
                ' MSTransitionEnd', function (e) {
                console.log(e.originalEvent.propertyName);
                //visibility transitions way too soon
                if (e.originalEvent.propertyName == 'top') {
                    $('#' + card.attr('id') + '-placeholder').remove();
                    card.css({
                        'top': '',
                        'left': '',
                        'width': '',
                        'height': '',
                        position: ''
                    }).removeClass('top');
                    console.log('end');
                    card.off('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd' +
                        ' MSTransitionEnd');
                }
            });
```

Also, I had to use `on` instead of `one`, because then only the visibility fired, therefore I had to manually `off` it afterwards.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, however the question in this case is far too broad. You haven't described the problem you're dealing with, so it's unclear what it is you're actually solving. Also note that 'tl;dr' is intended to be used to give a summary of a larger, more in depth article.

Comment: It is broad and if I were to simply ask it, I would provide more detail. But since I also provided an answer, I only wrote what was relevant. I could write a lot more, but it would be useless for the question, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: It's really not a great question, but the answer led me in the right direction. I wasn't aware that the transitionend event was triggered more often than requested, for unrelated properties. I could solve my problem with it.